# Spread operator for props are not passing to component

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I am having an issue passing spread operator props to components. Instead of returning a list with values, it is returning an empty list.

This is how I'm passing in my props to the component

```
const APIKey = "abc";
const url = "def";
const props = { APIKey, url}
return (
      <ProfileModal {...props} />
)
```

However, it is returning an empty list.

```
const FunctionName = (anotherPropIhave, props) => {
      const { APIKey, url } = props;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

React pass all props as first argument of react functional component.
So This is an object.

Correct way to get other *props* is , `...props`.

So:

```
const FunctionName = ({ anotherPropIhave, ...props }) => {
  const { APIKey, url } = props;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const APIKey = "abc";
const url = "def";
const props = { APIKey: APIKey, url: url}
return (
      <ProfileModal {...props} />
)
```

Comment: It won't make a difference. **{ APIKey: APIKey, url: url }** is same as **{APIKey, url}**.